# Incorrect syntax SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

Why do I get this error when I try to execute the following code?
I have a table NewTable1 with two columns: column1 and column2.

I get this error: Incorrect syntax near 'column2'.

```
--DROP COLUMN PROCEDURE

CREATE PROCEDURE DropColumn
    @tableName varchar(50),
    @columnName varchar(50)
AS

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);
        SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
         + ' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName);
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
    END
RETURN 0
GO

USE SKI_SHOP;
EXEC DropColumn 'NewTable1', 'column2';
GO
```

Comment: I don't think table/column name could be a variable. not 100% sure though

Comment: @Steve That's why op is using dynamic SQL

Comment: do you have a better idea? :d any tips? @Steve

Comment: Is SKI_SHOP the same DB you created the SP in? This code works fine for me in SQL Server 2012

Comment: try to print `@SQL` and execute that in sql or paste printed query here

Comment: It works for me as written.  Some kind of configuration issue -- permissions?  default database?

Comment: yes, it is. I don't get any other errors...i have some other procedures that work 100% correclty..like add a new column to a table etc

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: As a note:  the `return 0` is not part of the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. It works now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use appropriate data types. Also You will only be able to drop Columns  for tables in callers default schema. Since procedure doesn't take schema into consideration, therefore you can only pass the table name and if a table exists in other than caller default schema they wont be able to delete it using this procedure .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropColumn
    @tableName  SYSNAME,
    @columnName SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @SQL = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
          + N' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName);

      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
 END
GO
```

I over looked some basic simple issues in my first approach, whenever creating of Dropping objects in SQL Server always check if they exist, to avoid any errors . A more complete and safe approach would be something like ...

This time I have also added schema as a parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DropColumn
    @tableName  SYSNAME,
    @columnName SYSNAME,
    @Schema     SYSNAME,
    @Success    BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @SQL = N' IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables t 
                          INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                          ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                          INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
                          ON t.[schema_id] = sc.[schema_id]
                          WHERE t.name  = @tableName
                            AND c.name  = @columnName
                            AND sc.name =  @Schema)
                BEGIN
                  ALTER TABLE ' +  QUOTENAME(@Schema)+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
           + N'   DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName)
           + N'   SET @Success = 1; '
           + N' END 
               ELSE
                BEGIN
                  SET @Success = 0; 
                END '

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
                     ,N'@tableName SYSNAME, @columnName SYSNAME, @Schema SYSNAME, @Success BIT OUTPUT'
                     ,@tableName
                     ,@columnName
                     ,@Schema
                     ,@Success OUTPUT
 END
GO
```